# MySQL calling stored proc from inside transaction

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a software writing data to a MySQL database through stored procedures. The insert stored procedure called by the software (procedure A below) does the insert within a transaction in order to rollback if something fails.
After the insert, an update to another table needs to be made. The logic for this update is commonly used and therefore I would like to store it in a function or another stored procedure (procedure B below). The call to procedure B happens inside the transaction in procedure A because I'd like to rollback the insert done in procedure A if procedure B fails.

My issue is that the BEGIN statement in procedure B autocommits the transaction from procedure A since every procedure or function call begins its own transaction. Is it possible, and if so what is the best way, to store commonly used code (procedure B below) on the database that can be executed in transactions from other procedures?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A()
BEGIN
  -- some declarations and logic here
  START TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO TableA (
      ColA
    ) VALUES (1);

    CALL B();

  COMMIT;
END
  
CREATE PROCEDURE B()
BEGIN
  -- some declarations and logic here
  UPDATE TableB
  SET ColB = 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that the BEGIN statement in procedure B autocommits the transaction from procedure A since every procedure or function call begins its own transaction.

??? Where you have taken this from?

```
CREATE TABLE TableA SELECT 100 ColA;
CREATE TABLE TableB SELECT 100 ColB;
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A()
BEGIN
  -- some declarations and logic here
  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO TableA (
      ColA
    ) VALUES (1);

    CALL B();

--  COMMIT;
  ROLLBACK;
END
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE B()
BEGIN
  -- some declarations and logic here
  UPDATE TableB
  SET ColB = 1;
END
```

```
CALL A;
SELECT * FROM TableA;
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

| ColA |
| --- |
| 100 |

| ColB |
| --- |
| 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R6VT4SW_)

If BEGIN in procedure B() committed a transaction, then the INSERT would be committed, and TableA would contain two records.